# TelegramBot - переместить кнопку в новую строку

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram, бот

Как сделать так, чтобы кнопки были в столбце, а не в строке. Пример изображения, как мне нужно:

[image: пример]

Код PHP:

```
function sendInlineKeyboard($id_chat, $text, $array)
{
 $keyboard = array("inline_keyboard" => array($array));

        $toSend = array('method' => 'sendMessage', 'chat_id' => $id_chat, 'text' => $text, 'resize_keyboard' => true, 'reply_markup' => $keyboard);
        isset($mark) ? $toSend['parse_mode'] = $mark : '';
        isset($id_message) ? $toSend['reply_to_message_id'] = $id_message : '';     
        $ch = curl_init(API_URL);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($toSend));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
        $a = curl_exec($ch);
        return json_decode($a, true);           
}

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `test`");
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {             
            $array[] = array('text' => $row['city'], 'callback_data' => $id);
sendInlineKeyboard($user_id, 'String', $array);
}
```

Comment: на php точно не скажу, но для создания кнопок на c# нужно было создавать массив этих кнопок, и в одном массиве содержались кнопки всей строки.... то есть для создания кнопки на новой строке нужно было переместить каждую кнопку в новый массив.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно написали в комментарии, нужно передать массив, каждый элемент которого является массивом кнопок в строке (т.е. передаётся двумерный массив).

Вот пример, как это сделано у меня:

```
$start_keyboard_array = [
    ["Строка1"],
    ["Строка2"],
    ["Столбец1", "Столбец2"]
];

$start_keyboard = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup($start_keyboard_array, false, true);
```

Как это выглядит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. использую вот эту либу: https://github.com/TelegramBot/Api